# Rigorous proof of Taylor expansion for matrix square root

Tags: linear-algebra, probability-theory, asymptotics, taylor-expansion

Suppose that $A$ and $B$ are $n\times n$ positive definite diagonal matrices and $B$ is non-random. It is given that $A^2-B^2=O_p(n^{-1/2})$. Why is the following true?
$$
A=B+\frac{1}{2}B^{-1}(A^2-B^2)+o_p(n^{-1/2}).\tag{$*$}
$$
I can see why ($*$) is true *heuristically*:
$$
A^2=B^2+(A^2-B^2)=B^2[I+B^{-2}(A^2-B^2)].
$$
Then:
\begin{align*}
A{\color{red}=}\sqrt{A^2}&=B\sqrt{I+B^{-2}(A^2-B^2)}\\
&{\color{red}=}B\left[I+\frac{1}{2}B^{-2}(A^2-B^2)-\frac{1}{8}\Big(B^{-2}(A^2-B^2)\Big)^2+\cdots+\right]\\
&=B+\frac{1}{2}B^{-1}(A^2-B^2)-\frac{1}{8}B^{-1}\Big(B^{-2}(A^2-B^2)\Big)^2+\cdots\\
&{\color{red}=}B+\frac{1}{2}B^{-1}(A^2-B^2)+o_p(n^{-1/2}).
\end{align*}
I'm unsure about the equalities colored in red above.

Comment: What do $O_p$ and $o_p$ mean? (And what does it mean to say $B$ is ""non-random"?)

Comment: @DavidC.Ullrich Those are big O and small o in probability notation.

Answer (score 0):

Since $A,B$ are diagonal, they commute and all obviously works; the residual term is $O(1/n)$ if $B$ is a constant matrix.